# How to aggregate count data into a specific geographic location

Tags: r, aggregate, spatial, panel-data

I have a dataset called 'model_data', in which the unit of observation is a geographic cell (*gid*) taken from the UCDP PRIO-GRID data. This is simply a standardised spatial grid structure that allows for finely-grained analysis at a very local level. I am researching the effect of power balance between actors in civil wars on their use of violence against civilians i.e. if actors perform well (operationalised as inflicting a majority of the battle deaths in any one *gid*) will they target more or less civilians in the same *gid*. To this end, I have merged my dataset using an inner_join (by *gid*) with a dataset containing all individual incidents of armed violence (UCDP Georeferenced Events Dataset).

When I merge, the resulting dataset consists of duplicate *gid* observations for each individual incident of violence from the GED dataset. I need to find a way of aggregating all civilians deaths, all side_a deaths, and all side_b deaths in each specific *gid*, so that each observation in the dataset is a unique *gid* with all data on various types of deaths from that *gid*.

```
    model_data <- inner_join(grid, ged, by = c("year", "gid" = "priogrid_gid", "xcoord" = "longitude", "ycoord" = "latitude"))
```

[image]

As you can see from the first column, there are multiple observations with the same *gid*. I would like to aggregate all the data from the observations with the same *gid* into one observation.

I've researched a lot on how the best way to do this, but have been unsuccessful as of yet. From what I gather, the aggregate() function from the "sp" package would be my best bet, but I cannot work out how to use it in the way I need! Thank you for any help that may come my way

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
library(dplyr)

model_data %>%
    select(-id) %>%
    distinct()
```

Assuming just using the "gid" without the "id" will get you where you want to go.